# Chave estrangeira não UUID não pode ser implementada

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou criando tabelas em um banco Postgre, nas tabelas eu uso UUID como chave primária.
Para isso, executei: `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`
Então criei a primeira tabela com:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS documentos;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS documentos (
  id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
  nome VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  ativo INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  created_at VARCHAR (32),
  updated_at VARCHAR (32),
  UNIQUE(id)
);
```

O próxima tabela deveria ser a seguinte:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS diretores;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS diretores (
  id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
  nome VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  ativo INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  created_at VARCHAR (32),
  updated_at VARCHAR (32),
  inicio VARCHAR (12),
  documento VARCHAR (64),
  documento_id INTEGER REFERENCES documentos(id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    UNIQUE(id)
);
```

Porém ao executar o SQL acima me é retornado o erro: `foreign key constraint "diretores_documento_id_fkey" cannot be implemented`.
Por que essa chave não pode ser implementada, sendo que declarei que ela será única e a extensão já foi declarada?

Comment: E por que faz isso? O maior motivo para usar UUID é não ter que gerar o `id` no servidor, quando faz isso tem desvantagens que raramente compensa o uso, pode justificar a escolha?

Comment: Então @Maniero, isso foi uma indicação que recebi de um colega de equipe. O ideal seria criar a coluna id como text e inserir o UUID via código?

Comment: Verifique sua declaração de chave estrangeira. O tipo de dado `uuid` tem 128 bits enquanto que um `int` tem 32 bits (4 bytes).

Comment: Eu reparei que em `documento_id INTEGER REFERENCES documentos(id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION` estou realmente declarando INTEGER, como disse. Declarei como tipo uuid, porém estou intrigado com o que o @Maniero disse e gostaria de fazer usando boas práticas, o banco é muito grande e não quero pesar no desempenho.

Comment: @FilipeMachado o ideal pro seu caso eu não sei, pode ser, indicações são sempre complicadas porque você não sabe se a pessoa sabe o que está dizendo, se ela apenas aprendeu um receita de bolo e está repassando sem pensar no que é aquilo e principalmente se serve para seu caso. Aqui tem várias perguntas sobre o assunto com respostas bem avaliadas por profissionais competentes e pode tomar uma decisão melhor do que seguir o que alguém disse. Pode ser que nem seja o caso de gerar um UUID.

Comment: Então @Maniero, nesse caso eu realmente preciso que seja UUID pelo fato da aplicação servir em rede interna, assim como em rede externa, do contrário acontecerá conflitos quando os dados se encontrarem. Obrigado pelas dicas, com certeza vão me servir como fonte pra encontrar o caminho correto e banco de dados não é meu ponto forte.

Comment: @FilipeMachado não, o banco de dado sequer sabe se é rede interna ou externa, o que funciona em uma funciona na outra igual. Isso não faz sentido. A forma como cria é que muda, se fizer certo um `id` normal é válido e mais vantajoso. O UUID é necessário se não quer que o servidor crie o `id`. Nesse caso você tem o pior dos dois mundos, as desvantagens de ter o `id` sequencial e as desvantagens de usar UUID. Existe motivo para usar o UUID em outras situações, mas não parece ser o caso, pelo mesmo não justificou de forma que mostre isso.

Comment: A não ser que esteja falando de bancos de dados diferentes que são mesclados. Mas aí eu pergunto se realmente precisa fazer isso, porque é algo bem complicado de administrar, não é só o `id` que pode conflitar. Mesmo um caso assim se realmente não pode ser de outro jeito, o UUID pode ser evitado (aí já não tá claro qual estratégia é a mis aceitável no cenário). Ainda neste caso pode ser melhor gerar na aplicação.

Comment: @Maniero entendi o seu ponto de vista e realmente é um argumento muito forte, vou rever a inclusão do UUID. Muito obrigado. Por favor, faça a sua colocação à respeito da solução para que eu possa dar upvote e fechar a pergunta.